# Gnome on Xorg and Wayland

Tags: gnome, icons, wayland

I am running Ubuntu 17.10 on Wayland and am using workarounds for the known issues such as not being able to use sudo in gui's. Sometimes I need to run Ubuntu 17.10 on Xorg because of issues where I haven't been able to find a workaround yet, such as using the nVidia GPU.

Enough background, now to my question: When I run Ubuntu 17.10 on Wayland I get all of my icons and indicators in the top bar, for instance psensor which is very useful to just click on to check the CPU temp etc. When I run Ubuntu 17.10 on Xorg the psensor icon is missing and I need to launch the app to use it. Previously, in 17.04 on Gnome (Xorg) the psensor icon did used to appear in the top bar. Other icons are also missing or not loading properly on Xorg, for instance the OpenWeatherMap never actually loads. Why are the icons appearing on the new Wayland desktop but not on the older Xorg desktop?

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is an issue with using "ubuntu on xorg" option in ubuntu 17.10. I have strange behavior, my screen was starting to rotate itself vertically and horizontally and 
I fixed this issue by selecting unity from gear icon in the login screen. I think these issues are related to the current graphics drivers is not somehow supporting these new gnomes